# Android Authentication

Tags: android, web-services, rest, authentication

I am trying to create and Android app that requires the user to be authenticated (through a REST web service). The app has multiple activities and screens that all require the user to be logged in, when logged in the user can add and edit posts on a website.

I have read that using a AndroidHttp Client within a "ConnectionManager" singleton would be the best way to do it. However where would I go about storing the users details (username, password), would this be in the singleton? Should I authenticate each time the user try's to edit/add something?

Should I have a class like this:

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    private static ConnectionManager instance = null;
    private AndroidHttpClient client;

    private ConnectionManager() {
        client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android-Connection-Manager");
    }

    public static ConnectionManager getInstance() {
        if( instance == null ) {
            instance = new ConnectionManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void authenticate(String username, String password) {
        //Check for authentication here
    }
}
```

and call the below code every time the user does something:

```
private static ConnectionManager conn = ConnectionManager.getInstance();
conn.authenticate();
```

**OR**

should I store the users details in the singleton

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    private static ConnectionManager instance = null;
    private AndroidHttpClient client;

    private AppUser mLoggedInUser;
    private boolean mAuthenticated;

    private ConnectionManager() {
        client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android-Connection-Manager");
    }

    public static ConnectionManager getInstance() {
        if( instance == null ) {
            instance = new ConnectionManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void InitialiseUser(String username, String password) {
            //Do login checks here then return true if logged in
            mAuthenticated = true;
    }

    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
            return mAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control of the Rest Service, you could authenticate using the username\password on the initial connection and then return a "token" to your app if authentication succeeds.

Your app could then add this token to the http headers of all future requests and your service could check that it is valid before proceeding.

That is how I did it and it works well.

Comment: That seems to make sense, is this method secure? And do you know of any examples of how to achieve this?

Comment: You would need to use SSL to be secure but that is true for any service. I dont know of any documented examples but it isnt difficult.

Comment: Yeah I thought that it would probably be fine. I have just had a little look and it does seem very simple. It is just a matter of adding the header in the android app (HttpGet addheader) then checking it at the web service end right? I'm not missing anything am I?

Comment: Thats pretty much all I did. You could pass the token in the querystring too if you prefer.

Comment: 2 years late, but does anyone mind sharing some code on how I can do this? I'm having the same issue with the Android app I'm writing.
My question is here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559660/android-authentication-using-json

Comment: Isn't this the same as oAuth?