# Android authentication using JSON

Tags: android, python, json, django, authentication

I have a Python/Django server that is the API for a web service.
I'm building an Android application that will communicate with the API and authenticate users, and enable them do all pulls/pushes from the server.

My trouble is with the particular communication with the server. Currently I use my WiFi network, and run the server like so `python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.3:8000` so that it is available to any test device on my LAN.

The API is written so it returns **http status messages** with every response, so that I can tell the success or failure of a request before parsing the JSON reply.

On my Android side, I have used `HttpURLConnection` because it has the `getHeaderField(null)` method that I use to pick the *http status message* from the response. I get a status message *200 [success]* when I 'ping' my server - this is a sort-of proof of concept.

My real issue is authentication. My API requires I send it a JSON with data, and it returns a JSON response [with an http status message in the head].
I can't seem to figure out how to do this. The JSON action I've seen around the interwebs are merely picking, or posting.
I am wondering how I can POST and pick up a response from the server.

**Extra information**
- Server supports HEAD and GET and OPTIONS.
- Assuming server home is 192.168.1.3, user login/register would be in 192.168.1.3/user, events would be in 192.168.1.3/events and so on..
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154645/android-authentication) was the closest I got to figuring out a solution, but not quite..

**CODE from the AsyncTask**

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params)  {
publishProgress(true);

/*Create a new HttpClient and Post Header*/
JSONObject result=null;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
try {

    URL url = new URL(cons.PROTOCOL,cons.SERVER,cons.PORT,"/user");
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toURI());
HttpResponse response =null;

    /*Add your data*/
JSONObject j1=new JSONObject();
JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
j1.put("username", "test");
j1.put("email","test@test.com");
j1.put("password","password");
j1.put("first_name","John");
j1.put("last_name","Doe");
json.put("user",j1);
json.put("mobile_number","256774622240");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());  
se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
httppost.setEntity(se);

    /*Execute HTTP Post Request*/
    response= httpclient.execute(httppost);

        Log.i("jazz","It's ALIVE!!!!!");
        Log.i("jazz",response.getStatusLine().toString());

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    /* TODO Auto-generated catch block*/
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}



return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I'm now answering my own question :D

The issue was with the `path` variable in the `URL string`.
This is the format of one of the URL constructors based on this [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html).
`URL(String protocol, String host, int port, String file)`

Since I am posting the **JSON** to the `/user` path, that's the one I insert into the constructor as the `directory.`
So, my URL was formed like so:
`URL url= new URL("http",cons.SERVER,cons.PORT,"/user/");`

My mistake in the beginning was using `/user` instead of `/user/`
but other than that, the **URL structure and connections** are all alright.

Answer (score 1):

If your are building your HttpPostRequest well, and you only want to know how to attach JSON, here you are a possible solution for it:

```
  StringEntity formEntity = new StringEntity(yourJsonObject.toString());
  yourPostRequest.setEntity(formEntity);
```

I hope this helps!

PS:In addition, let me recommend you the use of this component:

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidHttpRestService

I've used it in an Android app that is connecting to a python server API and it makes http request easier for your Android client.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'm going to check out the RestService! 
In the meantime, I do have StringEntity in my code, and am using URL to set the path /user.
however, I get a 405 telling me POST is not allowed when I trigger the call. Since the only place POST is not allowed on the API is the home, it means that my trigger isn't sending the JSON POST data to my server/user folder, and is sending it to server/ instead.

Could you be knowing what the cause of this is? 
Thanks again!!

Comment: I've added code from the AsyncTask to the question :)

Comment: have try to give a simple String to the httpPost constructor. Maybe there is something wrong in the parameter for building your URI object. I'm not sure about your error, but it seems to be a server side error,not a client one. The only error that could have sense to me is the one you said related to the paths

Comment: Aaah, I see! You might be right. I've reworked the URL building so it now functions alright. Also, I fixed the JSON to fit the POST parameters and I still get a server response 500 when I post to the /user path. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :) Please mark the answer as the correct one if it really is!! :)